# Show that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}gd\lambda=\int\limits_{X}g\circ fd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Show that

1. $\lambda(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$ defines a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
2. Show that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}gd\lambda=\int\limits_{X}g\circ fd\mu$ for every Borel function $g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$

Here I was able to prove the part 1.
But I'm struggling with part 2.

I know that the integral of $g$ is defined with the suprimum of the integrals of simple functions $\phi\leq g$.

So I was first trying to prove the result for simple functions:
Thus let $\phi(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k=n}a_k\chi_{E_k}(x)$ be a simple function.

So $\int\phi d\lambda=\sum a_k\lambda(E_k)=\sum a_k\mu(f^{-1}(E_k))$
And after that I cannot see a proper way to proceed.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Note that $(\phi\circ f)(x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k \chi_{E_k}(f(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_{f^{-1}(E_k)}(x)$. In other words, $\phi \circ f = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \chi_{f^{-1}(E_k)}$ is a simple function on $X$, so $\int_X\phi\circ f \, d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \mu(f^{-1}(E_k)) = \int_{\Bbb{R}}\phi\, d \lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality for simple functions is proven in the comments. For a general non-negative function we can proceed as shown below.

For any $g \geq 0$ [there is](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measurable_Function_Pointwise_Limit_of_Simple_Functions) a  non-decreasing sequence $(\alpha_n)$ of simple functions pointwise convergent to it. We then have:

$$(\alpha_n\circ f)(x) =  \alpha_n(f (x))  \leq  \alpha_{n+1}(f(x)) \rightarrow  g(f(x))      $$

By [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) we get:

$$ \int_{\mathbf{R}} \alpha_n d\lambda =\int_{X}  \alpha_n\circ f d\mu \rightarrow \int_X  g\circ f  d\mu  $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer